# Combining tapply and 'not in' logic, using R

Tags: r, notin, tapply

How do I combine the tapply command with 'not in' logic?

**Objective**: Obtain the median sepal length for each species.

```
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, median)
```

**Constraint**: Remove entries for which there is a petal width of 1.3 and 1.5.

```
!iris$Petal.Width %in% c('1.3', '1.5')
```

**Attempt**:

```
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, median[!iris$Petal.Width %in% c('1.3', '1.5')])
```

Result: error message 'object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'.

**---**

My attempt here with the iris dataset is a stand-in demo for my own dataset. I have attempted the same approach with my own dataset and received the same error message. I imagine something is wrong with my syntax. What is it?

Comment: `median[!iris$Petal.Width %in% c('1.3', '1.5')]`
you are subsetting a function here. This yields in an error. You cant use [ ]  on functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
with(iris[!iris$Petal.Width %in% c('1.3', '1.5'),], tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, median))
# setosa versicolor  virginica 
#    5.0        5.8        6.5
```

The idea here is to operate on the subset-ted data in the first place.

Your line didn't work because the `FUN` argument should be applied on `X` (`Sepal.Length` in your case) rather over the whole data set.

Answer (score 1):

This is the workaround you should *not* do:

```
tapply(
  1:nrow(iris),
  iris$Species,
  function(i) median(iris$Sepal.Length[
     (1:nrow(iris) %in% i) &
    !(iris$Petal.Width %in% c('1.3', '1.5'))
]))
```

Things get ugly if you subset after splitting the vector in this way. You effectively have to

- split it again (when using `1:nrow(iris) %in% i`) and
- compute the subset once for each value of `iris$Species` (when using `!(iris$Petal.Width %in% c('1.3', '1.5'))`).